# Как в запросе заменить wm_concat на listagg?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Никак не могу удачно заменить `wmsys.wm_concat` на `wmsys.listagg`.

```
select 
  '.' || wmsys.wm_concat(A.description) as EXPR 
from 
  (
    select 
      distinct 1 as "Z", 
      server_name || '.' || func_name as description 
    from 
      reglament 
    where 
      record_status in (3, 4) 
      and (
        mstype_current <> 0 
        or upper(message) like '%ALERT%' 
        or upper(message) like '%ERROR%' 
        or upper(message) like '%ODBC%' 
        or upper(message) like '%REPAIR%'
      ) 
      and filial_id = 1111 
    UNION 
    select 
      B.X + B.Y + B.W as "Z", 
      B.description 
    from 
      (
        select 
          distinct case when ALERT_PERIOD - (
            LAST_PROCESSING_DATE - LAST_PROCESSING_DATE_OK
          ) 243600 < 0 
          and stype = 4 
          and SERVER_NAME not like 'CDBFUNC' then '1' else '0' end as "X", 
          case when ALERT_PERIOD - (
            LAST_PROCESSING_DATE - LAST_PROCESSING_DATE_OK
          ) 243600 < 0 
          and stype = 4 
          and SERVER_NAME like 'CDBFUNC' then '1' else '0' end as "W", 
          case when ALERT_PERIOD /(24 * 3600) - (
            LAST_PROCESSING_DATE - LAST_PROCESSING_DATE_OK
          ) < 0 
          and stype in (5, 6) then '1' else '0' end as "Y", 
          server_name || '.' || func_name as description 
        from 
          reglament 
        where 
          record_status in (3, 4) 
          and ALERT_ERRRESULT = '1' 
          and filial_id = 1111
      ) B
  ) A 
where 
  A.Z = 1
);
```

Comment: А что конкретно не получается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите следующий пример и сделайте аналогичные изменения в запросе.

```sql
create table t1 as 
    select mod (level,2)+1 id, 'description '||level description 
    from dual connect by level<=5;

11g> select id, wm_concat (description) descriptionlist
from t1
group by id
/
        ID DESCRIPTIONLIST                                                                 
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 description 2,description 4                                                     
         2 description 1,description 5,description 3                                       

12c> select id, listagg (description, ',') within group (order by null) descriptionlist
from t1
group by id
/
        ID DESCRIPTIONLIST                                                                 
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 description 2,description 4                                                     
         2 description 1,description 3,description 5
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, получилось!

Comment: Рад был помочь! В следующий раз постарайтесь давать в вопросе более короткий пример запроса. Посмотрите мой пример, это всего несколько строк.